# preg_replace efficiency

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, str-replace

I am using preg_replace for buzzword type functionality, using a list of buzzwords, searching for them in an article and then using preg_replace to wrap a link around them.

My buzzwords are:

```
Online Marketing
Social Media Markeing
Social Media
Social
Brand Marketing
Brand
Search Engine Optimisation
SEO
Email Marketing
Email
Twitter
Facebook
LinkedIn
```

and I am doing my preg_replace like this...

```
$text = preg_replace("/Online Marketing/", "<a href='".$base."online-marketing/'>Online Marketing</a>", $text);
```

but the issue is I am having to do a preg_replace for each possible variation like so...

```
$text = preg_replace("/Online Marketing/", "<a href='".$base."online-marketing/'>Online Marketing</a>", $text);
$text = preg_replace("/Online marketing/", "<a href='".$base."online-marketing/'>Online marketing</a>", $text);
$text = preg_replace("/online marketing/", "<a href='".$base."online-marketing/'>online marketing</a>", $text);
```

Which is extremely long winded, now I know that I can use an array with str_repalce like this:

```
$from = array("Online Marketing", "Online marketing", "online marketing");
$name = str_replace($from, "", $text);
```

But I cannot see a way of finding which part of the array was matched and then replacing it with the correct link, as you can see the str_replace above just totally deletes my buzzword, its just an example.

So I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me find a way of using an array of buzzwords in a str_replace or preg_replace but also make sure that it repalces the buzzword with the correct link.

Hope someone can help

Comment: I have got it all working now and finished, thanks all, I will post code tomorrow showing how I did it as i need to wait 8 hours because im only 61 Rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a mixture of all of your answers and this is my finished result...

```
$Fbuzzwords = array(" online marketing", " social media marketing", " social-media-marketing", " social media", 
                " social", " brand marketing", " brand", " search engine optimisation", " seo", " email marketing", 
                " email", " e-mail marketing", " e-mail", " tiwtter", " facebook", " linkedin");

$Ubuzzwords = array("online-marketing", "social-media-marketing", "social-media-marketing", "social-media-marketing", 
                "social-media-marketing", "brand-marketing", "brand-marketing", "search-engine-optimisation", 
                "search-engine-optimisation", "online-marketing", "online-marketing", "online-marketing", 
                "online-marketing", "social-media-marketing", "social-media-marketing", "social-media-marketing");

$i = 0;

foreach ($Fbuzzwords as $buzzword)
{
    $url = $Ubuzzwords[$i];

    $Rbuzzwords = array(" <a href='".$base.$url."/'>online marketing</a>", " <a href='"
.$base.$url."/'>social media marketing</a>", 
                " <a href='".$base.$url."/'>social-media-marketing</a>", " <a href='".$base.$url."/'>social media</a>", 
                " <a href='".$base.$url."/'>social</a>", " <a href='".$base.$url."/'>brand marketing</a>", 
                " <a href='".$base.$url."/'>brand</a>", " <a href='".$base.$url."/'>search engine optimisation</a>", 
                " <a href='".$base.$url."/'>seo</a>", " <a href='".$base.$url."/'>email marketing</a>", 
                " <a href='".$base.$url."/'>email</a>", " <a href='".$base.$url."/'>e-mail marketing</a>", 
                " <a href='".$base.$url."/'>e-mail</a>", " <a href='".$base.$url."/'>tiwtter</a>", 
                " <a href='".$base.$url."/'>facebook</a>", " <a href='".$base.$url."/'>linkedin</a>");

    $replacement = $Rbuzzwords[$i];

    $text = preg_replace("/$buzzword/i", "$replacement", $text);

    $i++;
}
```

So I have 3 arrays, 1 for finding the word on the page, and 2 for the url, I loop though all of the text for each part of the array making sure I catch every case

Answer (score 2):

```
$test = preg_replace("/online marketing/i", "<a href='".$base."'online-marketing/'>$0</a>, $text);
```

Or, if maintaining capitalisation is not important:

```
$test = str_ireplace("online marketing", "<a href='".$base."'online-marketing/'>online marketing</a>, $text);
```

Comment: I see so `/i` will do a search for the string in all case types? what about the output? will it recognise where the capital letters are and output them in the same place too?

Comment: $0 will be where the match is put, case is preserved.

Comment: @AdriftUniform: Yes, it will replace `$0` with the string that was matched, exactly as it was.  (Ps. Kolink, you have some double quotes missing from your examples.)

Comment: brilliant thanks! so would it be possible to do something like...

`$array = ("online marketing", "social media marketing", "brand marketing")`

`preg_replace("/$array/i", "<a href='".$base."'online-marketing/'>$0</a>, $text);`

Comment: You'd need to run a `foreach` and `preg_replace` one buzzword at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Function preg_replace can receive a second array of replacements.
If you are going to use always the same syntax, you can do a loop to generate the link (instead of writing it yourself each time you want to had an element)

```
$base = 'base/';
$from = array("Online Marketing", "Online test", "offline test");
$to = array();
foreach($from AS $key=>$f) {
   $from[$key] = "/".$f."/";    
   $to[$key]="<a href='".$base.$f."/'>online marketing</a>";
}
$string = 'this is a test using Online Marketing and offline test';
$text = preg_replace($from, $to, $string);
```

Comment: i see what your doing here but i dont think its quite what im looking for, thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_ireplace() with arrays (which is a case insensitive match string replacement), so if a certain match is found, it will replace it with the corresponding replacement in the other array.

EG:

```
$needles = array("Online Marketing", "Online Games", "Online Shopping");

$replacements = str_replace('<a href="online_marketing.html>Online Marketing</a>"',
                             '<a href="online_games.html">Online Games</a>',
                             '<a href="online_shopping.html">Online Shopping</a>');

    $replaced = str_ireplace($needles, $replacements);

    // Show the replaced text
    echo $replaced;
);
```

Comment: i need it to be case sensitive so i will be using pre_replace ("/.../i", "", $text);